# ERROR in node_modules/error-stack-parser/error-stack-parser.d.ts(9,5)

Tags: angular, node-modules, npm-scripts

I am trying to build an old angular project using the command npm run build, however I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/error-stack-parser/error-stack-parser.d.ts(9,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.     
node_modules/error-stack-parser/error-stack-parser.d.ts(9,17): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

When I navigate to error-stack-parser.d.ts file there's no missing semicolon. How can I bypass this error?

Comment: Did you try to remove node modules and reinstall them? Maybe you are running an old version?

Comment: I did, and still same error. the project that I am trying to build is old though.